# Issue with converting string to int

Tags: c#

Im running into a bit of an issue converting a `string` to `int`, char by char. When I step through the code, each `char` in the `string` is being converted to its ASCII representation. So for example, a `0` is being converted to `48`.

What I am trying to do, is to take a 4-digit number, take each digit and do something different.

As an example, if `date1` is `0415`, `num1` should be 0, `num2` 4, `num3` 1 and `num4` 5.

```
foreach (char c in date1)
{                
    switch (num)
    {
        case 1:
            // calculate first number
            cNum = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            num1 = c * 1;
            break;

        case 2:
            // calculate second number
            cNum = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            num2 = c * 2;
            break;

        case 3:
            // calculate third number
            cNum = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            num3 = c * 3;
            break;

        case 4:
            // calculate fourth number
            cNum = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            num4 = c * 4;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    num++;
}
```

Any assistance is very much appreciated and if anything else is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Why not using a for loop?

Comment: That's a weird way to do this, but why in the world are you multiplying the results by 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively?

Comment: It should probably be   `num1 = cNum * 1;`  You are trying to multiple the character and not the one you converted to an int.  Also if you are incrementing `num++` you can remove the switch statement and do something like `numarray[num] = cNum * (num+1)`

Comment: char c is '1', not 1 (for example). Give it a shot, see where you get.

Comment: Is there an exception? Are the results different than you expect? Not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: @BlackBear, Im not much of a C# programmer, just thought the foreach looked cleaner.. ./shrug.

Comment: @lucuma.  Woops..  forgot to change c to cNum, although 0 still comes out as 48, not 0..

Comment: @Jcl.  Its a long story but basically I need to take a 4 digit number and calculate a single digit code.  The first digit needs to be multiplied by 1, the second by 2, third by 3 and 4th by 4.  So with the example 0415, the final number should be 4.. 0+8+3+20=31=3+1=4..  But the issue is that I am getting ascii, not the actual number.  so 0 is being converted into 48..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using GetNumericValue instead of Convert.ToInt32().

Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue.aspx

Also - you could probably simplify your code to this unless I am missing something:

```
num1 = Char.GetNumericValue(date1[0]);
num2 = Char.GetNumericValue(date1[1]);
num3 = Char.GetNumericValue(date1[2]);
num4 = Char.GetNumericValue(date1[3]);
```

This seems kind of weird to me, but your loop is only processing the first 4 characters anyway.

If you want to handle more than 4 I would go back to using a loop and just push all of the numbers into an array or something instead of creating a specific variable for each.

Comment: Thanks Abe.  Its only ever going to be 4 characters, so thats why I did it like that.  I know its super ugly but I just wanted to get something quick and functional.

Answer (score 2):

[`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871.aspx) is behaving exactly as documented:

> A 32-bit signed integer that represents the UTF-16 encoded code point of the value parameter.

You can use [`Char.GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.char.getnumericvalue.aspx) to get the numeric value of a character, or if you know that it's in the range '0'-'9' you can just use:

```
int digit = c - '0';
```

This is sometimes simpler than calling `Char.GetNumericValue`, as the latter returns `double` so that it can represent values such as ¼. If you *do* only want to handle '0'-'9', it would be best to validate that:

```
if (c < '0' || c > '9')
{
    // Throw an exception or something like that
}
```

Additionally, note that if `date1` really is meant to be a date representation, don't do all of this yourself - use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) (or `TryParseExact`).

Comment: Thanks so much.  I dont usually code in C# so was pretty sketchy on how to do this, obviously, lol.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your case statements are looking for the ASCII value `1, 2, 3,...`, rather than the character values. Change your case statements to match:

```
case '1':
case '2':
...
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it's actually the `Convert.ToInt32` calls which aren't doing what the OP wants.

Comment: Ah yep, you are right. Well, the great Jon Skeet beat me to the punch again!